# What is Part of speech (POS) tag in natural language processing

Tags: nlp, data-mining, stanford-nlp

I am trying to get introduce by Stanford NLP package. I tried to execute few examples on my system.

for sentense: `I like it` it gives following result:

[image: Result]

Can some one please tell me what is `PRP` , `VBP`?
for sentence `It was very fantastic experience` it gives:

[image: Example 2]

**Can someone please elaborate this result?**

It can be tested here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp

I want to get sentiment result of the sentence. Whether +ve or -ve? with its score value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Stanford NLP documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/downloads/tagger.shtml) refers to [the Penn treebank documentation](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/J/J93/J93-2004.pdf) for the precise definitions.

However, if `PRP` == personal pronoun and `VBP` == present-tense verb were hard to guess, perhaps you should start with some NLP fundamentals before attempting this.

A part-of-speech tagger as such does not perform any sort of sentiment analysis.

Comment: thanks, I am pretty new with NLP. First shot of NLP with stanford package. Can you please tell me how and where does it gives sentiment result processing the text? I could get `negative or positive result` using `java -cp "*" -mx1g edu.stanford.n
lp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file input.txt` . Needs more elaborative result with sentiment score